# Detect when audio.play() has finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `audio.play()` inside my React project to trigger a clip onClick, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine when the clip has stopped playing so I can do something after it has finished.

```
class Soundboard extends Component {
    getAudio = (clipUrl) => {
        var audio = new Audio(clipUrl);
        return audio.play();
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <div
              onClick={() => this.getAudio(pathToClip)}
          />

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
audio.onended=function()
{
    alert("audio ended");
}
```